# exlcluir columna en jsPDF autotable

Tags: javascript, html, angular, jspdf, jspdf-autotable

tengo una problema estoy imprimiendo una tabla a través de jsPDF autotable y la tabla se me imprime bien, pero requiero eliminar una de las columnas que se imprimen y no se como hacerlo.

les dejo adjunto el código que estoy utilizando, tengo 11 columnas y necesito que la columna 5 no me se me imprima

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
    0: {cellWidth: 18},
    1: {cellWidth: 15},
    2: {cellWidth: 15},
    3: {cellWidth: 15},
    4: {cellWidth: 15},
    5: {cellWidth: 0},
    6: {cellWidth: 15},
    7: {cellWidth: 15},
    8: {cellWidth: 15},
    9: {cellWidth: 15},
    10: {cellWidth: 15},

  },margin: {top: 70,right:35,left:5}, styles: {overflow: 'linebreak',
  fontSize: 6},didParseCell: function (data) {

    var rows = data.table.body;
    if (data.row.index === rows.length - 1) {
        data.cell.styles.fillColor = [138, 236, 247];
    }} } )

  

  doc.output('dataurlnewwindow');
```